# Issue with RequestMapping POST API?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I can't fiure out what I am doing wrong here.  I am using the app "Postman" to send a request to a service.  The parameter is a very simple POJO shown below.  When I attempt to send the request I get a response: "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method"

Class used for request:

```
 public class LoginAttempt {

        private String userName;
        private String password;
        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }
        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }
```

API in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/validate", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json") 
public boolean validateUser(@RequestBody LoginAttempt login) {
    System.out.println("Login attempt for user " + login.getUserName() + login.getPassword());
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*FormHttpMessageConverter* which is used for @RequestBody-annotated parameters when content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded cannot bind target classes as *@ModelAttribute* can).
Therefore you need @ModelAttribute instead of @RequestBody

Either Use @ModelAttribute annotation instead of @RequestBody like this

```
     public boolean validateUser(@ModelAttribute LoginAttempt login)
```

or you can create a separate method form processing form data with the appropriate headers attribute like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/validate", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded" produces="application/json")
```

Comment: Thanks that got rid of the error from the back end but now the log statement is printing two null values for the instance variables for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Just try adding this bean:

```
<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="prefixJson" value="false"/>
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks that was it.  Except I am using Spring 4.X so it is org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter