# 415 Unsupported MediaType for POST request in spring application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have a very simple `Spring` Application (NOT spring boot). I have implemented a GET and POST controller methods. the `GET` method works fine. But the `POST` is throwing `415 Unsupported MediaType`. Steps to reproduce are available below

`ServiceController. java`

```
package com.example.myApp.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/service/example")
    public class ServiceController {

        @RequestMapping(value="sample", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
    public String getResp() {
        return "DONE";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="sample2", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getResponse2(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return "id is " + person.getId();
    }

}

class Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Person(){

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

`AppConfig.java`

```
package com.example.myApp.app.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.example.myApp")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/test/**").addResourceLocations("/test/").setCachePeriod(0);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(0);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/").setCachePeriod(0);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(0);
    }
}
```

`AppInitializer.java`

```
package com.example.myApp.app.config;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {


        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
                servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }


}
```

The code is available here:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/SpringDevSeattle/springrestcontroller.git
./gradlew clean build tomatrunwar
```

This spins up embedded tomcat.

Now you can curl the following

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:8095/myApp/service/example/sample"
```

works fine

But

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" '{
    "id":1,
    "name":"sai"
}' "http://localhost:8095/myApp/service/example/sample2"
```

Throws 415 unsupported MediaType

```
<body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 415 - </h1>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Status report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u></u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.</u>
        </p>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.54</h3>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution and I want to post here so it benefits others.

Firstly I need to include jackson in my classpath, which I added in build.gradle as follows:

```
 compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.5'
```

Next, I have to change my `AppConfig` which extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.example.myApp")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/test/**").addResourceLocations("/test/").setCachePeriod(0);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(0);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/").setCachePeriod(0);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(0);
    }


    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

That is all and everything worked nicely

Answer (score 6):

Accept Header might be the issue.
As far as i remember, when you send a request via curl it adds a default header `accept : */*`
But in case of JSON you have to mention the accept header
 as `accept : application/json` 
similarly you have mentioned the content-Type.

And little more, i dont know what is that, but don't you think you have to place "request mappings" like that

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sample" ...
@RequestMapping(value="/sample2" ...
```

This may not be the case, but accept header is the thing, i think is the main issue.

**Solution 2**
Since you have this code

```
public String getResponse2(@RequestBody Person person)
```

I have already faced this problem before and the solution two may help here

FormHttpMessageConverter which is used for @RequestBody-annotated parameters when content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded cannot bind target classes as @ModelAttribute can). Therefore you need @ModelAttribute instead of @RequestBody

Either Use @ModelAttribute annotation instead of @RequestBody like this

```
public String getResponse2(@ModelAttribute Person person)
```

I provided the same answer to somebody and it helped.
here is that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348438/issue-with-requestmapping-post-api/36348741#36348741) of mine

Comment: no it is not. I added accept header and it did not work either

Comment: Hey ! i updated my answer, i believe this is the issue.
Please check sloution 2 @brainstorm

Comment: @TahirHussainMir, hey i have added@ModelAttribute annotation.Control is hitting to the method but my object data is displaying null...?? any suggestion

Comment: check the names of variables of object and the name fields in the html. They should be same. Like if there is variable String myName; then in html, the input field should have attribute name="myName"

Answer (score 1):

can you trying using the -d option in curl

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d
 '{"id":"1,"name":"sai"}'
 http://localhost:8095/myApp/service/example/sample2
```

Also, if you use windows you should escape double quotes

```
-d "{ \"id\": 1, \"name\":\"sai\" }"
```