# Unsupported Media Type after request

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, spring-rest

I want to make POST request from Angular client. I have this Spring endpoint:

```
    @RestController()
public class HomeController {

  @PostMapping(value = "/payment/{unique_transaction_id}")
  public ResponseEntity<WpfResponse> handleWpfMessage(@PathVariable("unique_transaction_id") String unique_transaction_id,
      @RequestBody WpfPaymentsDTO transaction, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    /// .... 
    MessageProcessor messageProcessor = processors.getOrDefault(transaction.getTransaction_type(), defaultProcessor);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(messageProcessor.processMessage(merchant, contract, terminal.get(), transaction, request));
  }
}
```

I use this typescript code:

```
save(main: MainForm, hash: string): void {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/some_package/payment/ckjzqtyxh5pnavbjecujhuvzaa5q8n74', JSON.stringify(main), { headers }).subscribe();
  }
```

But when I run the code I get:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 415, statusText: "Unsupported Media Type", url: "http://localhost:8080/some_package/payment/ckjzqtyxh5pnavbjecujhuvzaa5q8n74", ok: false, …}error: nullheaders: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}lazyInit: ƒ ()lazyUpdate: nullnormalizedNames: Map(0) {}__proto__: Objectmessage: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/some_package/payment/ckjzqtyxh5pnavbjecujhuvzaa5q8n74: 415 Unsupported Media Type"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 415statusText: "Unsupported Media Type"url: "http://localhost:8080/some_package/payment/ckjzqtyxh5pnavbjecujhuvzaa5q8n74"__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

```
WpfPaymentsDTO:

public class WpfPaymentsDTO {

    private String transaction_id;

    private String transaction_type;

    private String currency;

    private Integer amount;
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the content type in the PostMapping as so :

```
@PostMapping(path = "/payment/{unique_transaction_id}", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
```

Here "application/json" is just a sample. You can give the suitable type.

Comment: It's not solving the issue. Other proposals?

Comment: I found the issue. The nI remove `@RequestBody WpfPaymentsDTO transaction` Its working fine. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have Jackson added and configured in your Spring application. Refer to this question:

[415 Unsupported MediaType for POST request in spring application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066591/415-unsupported-mediatype-for-post-request-in-spring-application)

Comment: No, I can't find a solution.

Comment: No to what? Do you have Jackson in your classpath? Do you have it configured in Spring configuration?